# Searching UNIX timestamp gives differing results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

The following queries give different results, the result for both should be two. I'm using timestamp columns in my db (postgres), and am searching for objects where their end_at column is less than or equal to a given UNIX timestamp.

```
puts object.time_records.where('time_records.end_at <= ?', object.time_records.second.end_at).count #=> 2 (Correct)
puts object.time_records.where('time_records.end_at <= ?', DateTime.strptime(object.time_records.second.end_at.to_i.to_s, '%s')).count # => 1 (Incorrect)
puts object.time_records.where('time_records.end_at <= ?', Time.at(object.time_records.second.end_at.to_i)).count # => 1 (Incorrect)
```

If I seed some data, the timestamp used in the query might be, for example:

```
1473024092
```

Then if I print the timestamps for the object:

```
puts object.time_records.pluck(:end_at).map(&:to_i)
```

I get the following results:

```
1472419292
1473024092
1473628892
1474233692
```

As can be seen from these, the correct result should be two. If anyone has encountered something similar I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

For what it's worth, this is occurring in specs I'm writing for a gem. I've tried varying combinations of `in_time_zone` and `.utc` for parsing and converting to the timestamp, and they all offer the same result. Even converting to a timestamp and straight back to a Time, and testing for equality results in false, when `to_s` is equal for both.

I ran an example in irb:

```
2.3.0 :001 > now = Time.now
 => 2016-08-28 21:58:43 +0100 
2.3.0 :002 > timestamp = now.to_i
 => 1472417923 
2.3.0 :003 > parsed_timestamp = Time.at(timestamp)
 => 2016-08-28 21:58:43 +0100 
2.3.0 :004 > now.eql?(parsed_timestamp)
 => false 
2.3.0 :005 > now == parsed_timestamp
 => false 
2.3.0 :006 > now === parsed_timestamp
 => false 
2.3.0 :007 > now.class
 => Time 
2.3.0 :008 > parsed_timestamp.class
 => Time
```

Comment: Does your db handle fractional times?

Comment: You can use my.custom.activerecord.query.to_sql to find out what is the SQL query that is actually being performed

Comment: @FrederickCheung that was the problem alright.

Comment: @Bustikiller thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fractional times. UNIX timestamps are to the second, so when converting `to_i`, the milliseconds are discarded.

Setting the precision of the timestamp columns resolved this issue:

```
class CreateTimeRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :time_records do |t|
      t.belongs_to :object, index: true, null: false

      t.datetime :start_at, null: false, index: true, precision: 0
      t.datetime :end_at, null: false, index: true, precision: 0

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```